# Does there exist a vector space $V$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, but is not a topological/smooth manifold of dimension $m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, category-theory, differential-topology

Does there exist a vector space $V$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, but is not a topological/smooth manifold of dimension $m$?

---

Suppose $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

In the category of vector spaces, $V$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^m$, but $V$ may not have a topology on it, so it may not be a topological manifold, and hence it can definitely not be a smooth manifold (since all smooth manifolds are just topological manifolds endowed with a smooth structure).

If $V$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, then we can conclude in that $V$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^m$ in the category of topological spaces, and $V$ must also be a topological manifold, however since every topological manifold is not a smooth manifold (see the [Exotic Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) as an example), we can't necessarily conclude that $V$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

---

So my question is the following, does an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ induce a homeomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, and furthermore does a homeomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ (along with the isomorphism between the two vector spaces) induce a diffeomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$?

If not could someone provide me with an example of a vector space $V$ which is  isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, but not homeomorphic, and also of an example of a vector space $V$ which is homeomorphic and isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$?

---

**Note:** Isomorphism here means isomorphism of vector spaces.

Comment: Unless you impose some condition on the topology of $V$ (like compatibility with the vector space structure of some form) the answer is of course no: pick a bijection from $V$ to the Cantor set $K$ and put on $V$ the unique topology which makes that bijection a homeomorphism.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense as stated.  A vector space is not a topological space at all, so it is meaningless to ask whether it is homeomorphic to something.  Do you mean to assume that some topology on the underlying set of $V$ has been chosen?  And do you intend to assume there is any connection whatsoever between the topology and the vector space structure?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes that's what I meant, that we assume some topology on the underlysing set of $V$ has been chosen. I don't however assume there is any connection between the topology and the vector space structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give whatever topology/smooth structure to $\mathbb R^n$ as you like without affecting it's vector space structure.

Consider $X=\mathbb R^n$ with the trivial topology, i.e. only two open subsets: the empty set and $X$. Then, this is not homeomorphic to the $Y=\mathbb R^n$ with the usual Euclidean topology. Then these are not homeomorphic spaces for many reasons (eg: $X$ is compact but $Y$ is not).

Again, let $X'=\mathbb R^n$ and find a bijection with $\mathbb R$ and use this bijection to make $X'$ a $1$ dimensional manifold. Of course this cannot be homeomorphic to $Y=\mathbb R^n$ which is an $n$-dimensional manifold for $n>1$.

Answer (score -1):

No. Change of base in V gives you a smooth function in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So you have a smooth structure which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$